# сделать слайс в мультииндексе с использованием Timestamp Pandas (реиндексировать мультииндекс для использования слайса по Timestamp)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, index, индексация

Имею датафрейм. Построен мультинденкс: (str, str, Timestamp).

`MultiIndex([...], names=['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия', 'Расчет', 'Дата инвестиции'], length=73012)`

Хочу отобрать значения датафрейма из диапазона дат, например: 2020-01-01 : 2020-12-31 (за год, включая левую и правую границы):

`df.loc[slice(None),slice(None), slice('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')]`

ловлю ошибку: "IndexingError: Too many indexers"

Пробую по-другому:

`start = pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01')
finish = pd.Timestamp('2020-12-31')
df.loc[slice(None),slice(None), slice(start, finish)]`

все равно ловлю ошибку: "IndexingError: Too many indexers"

Как правильно сделать слайс?

UPD:

увидел, что обращался неправильно, исправил:

`df.loc[(slice(None),slice(None), slice('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')), :]`

ловлю другую ошибку:

`UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted: slicing on levels [2], lexsort depth 0'`

Comment: третий вариант: df.loc[(slice(None),slice(None), slice(start, finish)), 'Сегмент'] ловит уже другую ошибку: "UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex slicing requires the index to be lexsorted: slicing on levels [2], lexsort depth 0'". Получается, проблема в построении индекса - должен быть каким-то образом отсортирован?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы уже ответили на собственный вопрос - для того, чтобы иметь возможность использовать срезы, индекс должен быть отсортирован.

Я бы еще посоветовал использовать [pd.IndexSlice[...]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html) для *multi-index slicing*:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[:, :, '2020-01-01':'2020-12-31'], :]
```

вместо:

```
df.loc[(slice(None),slice(None), slice('2020-01-01','2020-12-31')), :]
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет - применил, очень помогло - удалось снять в некоторых случаях ошибку "установления значения на копии слайса или индекса".

Answer (score 1):

Надо было отсортировать индекс после создания:

`df = df.set_index(['IDКлиента, Бизнес-Линия', 'Расчет'])
df = df.set_index('Дата инвестиции', append=True, drop=False)
df.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace=True)`